# Flutter unfocus textField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple TextFormField in which I need to show the date picker when the user clicks on TextField and sets the date and closes simply. All is working fine but the issue is date picker is not closing because of the focus issue when I select the date it reopens the date picker.

My code

```
   Container(
    width: Width * 0.45,
    child: FocusScope(
      child: Focus(
        onFocusChange: (focus) async {
          print("focus: $focus");
          DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

          final DateTime? picked =
              await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: selectedDate,
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900, 1),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2022));
          if (picked != null &&
              picked != selectedDate)
            setState(() {
              print(picked);
              print(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-d")
                  .format(picked)
                  .toString());
              bookDate.text =
                  DateFormat("yyyy-MM-d")
                      .format(picked)
                      .toString();
            });

          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: bookDate,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.date_range_outlined,
                color: Color(0xffbdbdbd),
              ),
            ),
            labelText: "Date",
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: textGreyColor,
                fontFamily: 'SegoeUI'),
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
                  width: 1.0),
            ),

            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius:
                  new BorderRadius.circular(10),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
            ),
            //fillColor: Colors.green
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
              color: kPrimaryColor),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

When I click on it its showing date picker fine but the date picker is not closing

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use `onTap` property of `TextFormField` instead of the Focus widget:

```dart
TextFormField(
  onTap: () async {
    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900, 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(2022),
    );

    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        print(picked);

        print(
          DateFormat("yyyy-MM-d").format(picked).toString(),
        );

        bookDate.text =
          DateFormat("yyyy-MM-d").format(picked).toString();
      });
    }
  },

  ...
)
```

If you provide a callback, you will be able to override the text form field's internal gesture detector. So, you can show the date picker dialog by calling `showDatePicker()` method when the field is tapped.